# C++ win32 async socket client send() issue

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, asynchronous, send

I have to write a WIN32, asynchronous socket client application, which connects to a server. I can launch the program, connect to the server, receive and proceed the received data, but when I try to send a message to the server, nothing happens on the server. I do not have any socket error message, and the send() function returns the correct sent bytes. But the server looks like it doesn't receive anything. My send() is called within the FD_READ statement, first if statement. I tried to move it to other statements (WM_CREATE, FD_WRITE, FD_CONNECT), but still the same issue. I tried to find what's wrong, look at many many forums since one mounth, but I do not find the problem. Any help would be very appreciated. Here is a sample of my code (I skipped the non interesting parts) :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include<process.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

#define IDC_BUTTON_CONNECT 101 // Button identifiers

#define IDC_EDIT_IP 102 // Edit / Text box identifiers
#define IDC_EDIT_PORT 103
#define IDC_EDIT_DEBUG 104
#define WM_SOCKET 105 // Socket messages structure identifier

HWND hWnd;
HWND hEditIp;
HWND hEditPort;
HWND hDebug;

HWND hButtonConnect;

HANDLE hReadMutex;

SOCKET Socket = NULL;
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
char *ip = "";
char *port = "";
bool connectStatus = FALSE;
char readBuffer[5000];
char id[32];
char version[256];

LPSTR statusText = TEXT("Connecting...");

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

// WinMain...

// appendTextToEdit function...

// incoming data processing thread (not used yet)...

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{   
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
        // Get IP and port from file "config.ini"...        

        //Create windows for IP, Port and Debug...

        // Create "connect" button...


        WSADATA WsaDat; // Winsock initialization...
        int nResult=WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WsaDat);
        if(nResult!=0)
        {
            statusText=TEXT("Winsock initialization failed");                   
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }

        Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP); // Creating socket...
        if(Socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            statusText=TEXT("Socket creation failed");                  
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }

        nResult=WSAAsyncSelect(Socket,hWnd,WM_SOCKET,(FD_CLOSE|FD_READ|FD_WRITE|FD_CONNECT)); // Select AsyncSocket events...
        if(nResult)
        {
            statusText=TEXT("WSAAsyncSelect failed");                   
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            break;
        }           

        // Set up our socket address structure...
        SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
        SockAddr.sin_port=htons(atoi(port)); 
        SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;        

        connect(Socket,(LPSOCKADDR)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr)); // Connexion command              
    }
    break;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        // painting / updating the window...
    }
    break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
            case IDC_BUTTON_CONNECT:
            {                   
                if(connectStatus==FALSE) // Avoid to reconnect when already online...
                {
                    // Window repaint with updated text (statusText = global variable)
                    statusText=TEXT("Connecting...");                   
                    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);                   

                    // Retrieve edit box datas and store to variables and file...
                    // Saving data to "config.ini" file...

                    // Reinitializing adress structure with new host adress and port from edit boxes, and reconnect attempt...
                    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
                    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(atoi(port));
                    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;    

                    connect(Socket,(LPSOCKADDR)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr));
                }
                break;
            }
            break;          
        }
        break;          

    case WM_SOCKET:
    {           
        switch(WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam))
        {
            case FD_CONNECT:
            {
                connectStatus = TRUE;
                statusText=TEXT("Connected");               
            }

            case FD_READ:
            {
                appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "FD_READ event...\n");

                char *rawVariable = nullptr;                    
                char *next_token = nullptr;                         

                recv(Socket, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer), 0);            

                rawVariable = readBuffer;               

                if(strstr(rawVariable, "id=") != NULL) // Identifying message sent by the server (starts with id, version, ...) and store the values to variables (working fine)
                {   
                    char *label = strtok_s(rawVariable, "=", &next_token);
                    char *pId = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token);  
                    rawVariable = strtok_s(NULL, "", &next_token);
                    strcpy_s(id, pId);

                    char message[256] = "Qh57=1"; // Setting up message structure... (the server should do an action when it receives "Qh57=1\r\n" but it doesn't...) here is my problem...
                    appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "Message sent : ");
                    appendTextToEdit(hDebug, message);
                    char *endline = "\r\n";
                    strcat_s(message, endline); 

                    string messageString(message);          
                    int messageLength = ((messageString.length()) - 2); // Get outgoing string length (-2)                          
                    int sent = send(Socket, message , messageLength , 0);               

                    char buffer [33]; // Display number of bytes sent...
                    _itoa_s(sent,buffer,10);                    
                    appendTextToEdit(hDebug, " (");
                    appendTextToEdit(hDebug, buffer);
                    appendTextToEdit(hDebug, " bytes sent)\n");
                }

                if( strstr(rawVariable, "version") != NULL)
                {
                    char *label = strtok_s(rawVariable, "=", &next_token);      
                    char *pVersion = strtok_s(NULL, "\n", &next_token); 
                    rawVariable = strtok_s(NULL, "", &next_token);      
                    strcpy_s(version, pVersion);    
                }                                       

                appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "End of FD_READ\n");           
            }
            break;

            case FD_WRITE:
            {
                appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "FD_WRITE event...\n");

                appendTextToEdit(hDebug, "End of FD_WRITE\n");
            }
            break; 

            case FD_CLOSE:
            {   
                statusText = "Disconnected from server";
                connectStatus = FALSE;
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
//              SendMessage(hWnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL); // Final version...                  
            }
            break;
        }
        break; 
    }
    break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        closesocket(Socket);
        WSACleanup();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    break;
}   
return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Comment: How do you know there's no problem with the server?

Comment: ^^^ what did Wireshark say?

Comment: In your `WM_SOCKET` handler, you are not checking for socket errors. `WSAGETSELECTEVENT()` tells you which operation triggered the event, and `WSAGETSELECTERROR()` tells you whether the operation was successful or not. For instance, if `connect()` fails, you will get an `FD_CONNECT` event with an error code other than 0. You are also not doing any error checking on `recv()` or `send()` at all, your parsing of the `rawVariable` data is incomplete, you are not actually sending the line break at the end of your outgoing message, etc.

Comment: Thank you. The line break is added at the end of the message (strcat function) by adding "\r\n" before to send. When I add WSAGetLastError test with int sent, I have no error return at all.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are sending an incomplete message to the server, so it is not going to do anything.  Per your own comments in the code:

```
the server should do an action when it receives "Qh57=1\r\n" but it doesn't...
```

It never receives the `\r\n`, because you are never sending it:

```
char message[256] = "Qh57=1";
...
char *endline = "\r\n";
strcat_s(message, endline); // <-- you do append a CRLF...

string messageString(message);          
int messageLength = ((messageString.length()) - 2); // <-- but you subtract the CRLF from the message length...
int sent = send(Socket, message , messageLength , 0); // <-- so the CRLF is not sent!
```

Do not subtract the CRLF from the message length:

```
int messageLength = messageString.length();
```

BTW, using a `std:string` just to calculate the message length is a waste of memory.  You can use `strlen()` instead:

```
int messageLength = strlen(message);
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH ! It is working now. I had the problem under my eyes for from the begening and didn't see it, Thanks again.

Comment: Please allow me one more question. Why do you say my parsing of rawVariable is incomplete ? I also think there is a problem, because I sometimes have the value of pId or pVariable which are wrong (other rawVariable substring values). For you understand, the rawVariable is a long string like : id=3\nversion=10.0.5\nQh57=0\nQs323=-999999\n and I sometimes have, for example the value of pVersion = -999999, but it should be 10.0.5

Comment: It is incomplete because TCP is a byte stream, not message oriented. `recv()` returns whatever is in the socket's receive buffer *up to* the requested number of bytes, which means it can return fewer bytes than requested. The only guarantee that `recv()` provides is that *at least* 1 byte will be returned on each read (if no error occurs). And the buffer you read into is not null terminated, either. But your code is assuming both cases, which is wrong. You might get `d=3\nve` on one `recv()`, then `rsion=10.0.5\nQh` the next time, then `57=0\nQs323=-999999\n`the next time. See the issue?

Comment: So, you need to copy received bytes from your receiving buffer into a more suitable container, like a `std::string` or `std::vector`, checking that container for completed messages after each read.  Read some bytes, append to container, extract completed messages. Read some bytes, append to container, extract completed messages. And so on.  A completed message could be when a delimiter is reached, like for a `\n`-terminated line, or it could be a specific number of bytes expected, like for a binary transfer. Whatever your protocol requires (which you provided no details for).

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Please see the following new post, which is specific for my incoming data processing issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827266/c-win32-async-client-incoming-data-processing

Answer (score 0):

A stream socket connection doesn't know anything about message boundaries. It just transports bytes, much like a RS232 connection. If you read the documentation of `recv` carefully, you will find that a successful `recv` call can "return" (=copy to the buffer) anywhere between one byte and the specified buffer size - depending on how much data has already been received. `recv`s return value will tell you how much has been copied. If more data follows, it will be returned by succeeding `recv` calls. That means if the server sends `id=3\nversion=10.0.5\nQh57=0\nQs323=-999999\n` your first `recv` call might return `id=3\nversion=10.0.5\nQh` and the second might then return `57=0\nQs323=-999999\n`. Or you might get it in 3 chunks. Or 4. Or even one byte at a time.

The easiest way to deal with this, which unfortunately has very bad performance, is to repeatedly call `recv` with a buffer size of one byte. Until you see that you have received the whole message (in your example this would be after 4 `\n` characters have been received).

The preferred way would be something like:

1. Call `recv` with a bigger buffer
2. Append however many bytes `recv` returned to your "message assembly buffer"
3. If the "message assembly buffer" contains at least one complete message: process and remove it. Repeat until all complete messages have been processed and removed.
4. Goto (1)